# Children's novel transported into knights/armour fantasy world?

Tags: story-identification, fantasy-genre

I'm looking for a children's/young adult novel, probably around the 100 page length. I don't remember much at all of the story, but the following is what I do remember:

The story involves some children (possibly just one child) who are somehow transported into a medieval fantasy world, where I think they inhabit adult bodies - I think a knight and/or priest of some sort. There is some sort of adventure that ends with a boy in the body of a knight deciding to stay in the world. The knight/child talks about *[noblesse oblige](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noblesse_oblige)* and somehow the phrase *[mea culpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mea_culpa)* comes into it, but I don't think in its religious sense, rather an indicator of the time period they are in and the use of classical languages by upper-class people then.

I guess some similarities to Narnia, but it is definitely not any of the Narnia series.

I've searched for books with those two phrases in them, but found nothing that rings a bell. I've also had a look through lists of books similar to the Narnia series, but nothing rings a bell.

I read it in a school library at least 30 years ago (late 1980s/early 1990s), but was probably written much earlier. I would hazard a guess at 1960s. It was written in English and is probably by an English as a first language author (i.e. not a translation), possibly a New Zealand or Australian author as the school was in New Zealand. I think it was not a part of a series.

As I recall it, the cover was a bright blue (sky) with a green hill (background) and a knight in the foreground, but my memory is very hazy on this.

Comment: Ahh, the storied, blissful, ancient era of Windows XP...

Comment: @Spencer Now I'm thinking of animating a knight *a la* Terry Gilliam over the background.